# No packages can be installed using PIP/PIp3 in Anaconda prompt

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda

The error message is:

```
(base) PS C:\Users\15257> pip --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Anaconda\Scripts\pip-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal.cli.main'
(base) PS C:\Users\15257> pip3 --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Anaconda\Scripts\pip3-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal.cli.main'
```

I tried to reinstall PIP, but it didn't work.
After I reinstall anaconda, pip works fine in the base environment, but after creating a new environment, pip does not work.

```
(base) PS C:\Users\15257> pip --version
pip 21.0.1 from D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.8)

(paddle_env) PS C:\Users\15257> pip --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\paddle_env\Scripts\pip-script.py", line 
6, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal.cli.main'
```

Comment: Your installation is messed up, but without information about how you messed it up in the first place, it's not really possible to guess how to unmess it.

Comment: Your best bet is probably to remove Conda completely and start fresh. Touch the `base` environment as little as possible and use separate environments for development, that is likely the cause of the issues here.